# How to get value from hbase and put it into a variable?

Tags: jruby, hbase, irb

This is probably a noob question, so I apologize in advance.

The HBase console, as far as I understand, is an extension (or a script running over) JIRB. Also, it comes with several HBase-specific commands, one of which is 'get' - to retrieve columns\values from a table.
However, it seems like 'get' only writes to screen and doesn't output values at all.

Is there any native hbase console command which will allow me to retrieve a value (e.g. a set of rows\columns), put them into a variable and retrieve their values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not a native console command in 0.92. If you dig into the source code, there is a class Hbase::Table that could be used to do what you want. I believe this is going to be more exposed in 0.96. At this point, I have resorted to adding my own Ruby to my shell to handle a variety of common tasks (like using SingleColumnValueFilters on scans).